# Yii2 - redirect if view file not exist

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I try to do something like a standard behaviour in Yii2 if the view file doesn't exist. 
For example if view 'xyz' not exist then redirect to another controller action or would it be easier if I just render then a standard view like a special 404 page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may do in your `controller` as below:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\base\ViewNotFoundException;

class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        // ...

        try
        {
            return $this->render('your-view', [
                // ...
            ]);
        }
        catch (ViewNotFoundException $e)
        {
            $this->redirect();
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Good work! If there any view-file-exists method by Yii2? Thanks.

Comment: @NickTsai There is not. In the source code, Yii2 first get the view path by [findViewFile](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/View.php#L166), then [renderFile](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/View.php#L219). Actually, Yii2 use `is_file` to test if `view` exists.

Comment: Thanks, @Paul. Then I believe using `file_exist` to check view in Yii2 is a bad idea, which need to combine the real path. Your way is good to handle the logic.